# bash grep not finding all instances of gene

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

**I have a file1 which has gene names:**

```
Appl
Bsg
mt:CoI
mt:CoII
mt:CoIII
```

**I have file2 which has all matches of those gene names in the genome:**

```
"FBgn0000108"; "Appl";
"FBgn0000228"; "Bsg25D";
"FBgn0013674"; "mt:CoI";
"FBgn0013674"; "mt:CoI";
"FBgn0013675"; "mt:CoII";
"FBgn0013676"; "mt:CoIII";
"FBgn0261822"; "Bsg";
"FBgn0000227"; "Bsg25A";
```

**I would like the output to include the lines that contain the reference IDs in file1:**

```
"FBgn0000108"; "Appl";
"FBgn0013674"; "mt:CoI";
"FBgn0013674"; "mt:CoI";
"FBgn0013675"; "mt:CoII";
"FBgn0013676"; "mt:CoIII";
"FBgn0261822"; "Bsg";
```

**I already tried**:

```
fgrep -wf file1 file2 > file3
```

**But this gets rid of mt:CoII and mt:CoIII because they contain mt:CoI:**

```
"FBgn0000108"; "Appl";
"FBgn0013674"; "mt:CoI";
"FBgn0261822"; "Bsg";
```

I would really appreciate some help on how to modify the grep command to get the desired output!

Comment: what grep (Free BSD or GNU)

Comment: With GNU `grep` on Debian I get the expected output exactly.

Comment: I was using the free BSD version, and downloaded the GNU version using brew install grep and it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: FreeBSD grep -w flag is broken